# C# Object to XmlElement

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

What is the best way to convert the C# object to `XmlEmenet`?
Do I just use `XmlSerializer` and import the `XmlNode` or is there a better way?

This is what I found out there wondering if there is any other better way.

```
public XmlElement Serialize(XmlDocument document)
{
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");
    XmlElement returnVal;
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(ms, UTF8Encoding.UTF8);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    tw.IndentChar = ' ';
    serializer.Serialize(tw, this, ns);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    doc.Load(ms);
    returnVal = document.ImportNode(doc.DocumentElement, true) as XmlElement;
    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: That depends. Why are you converting it to XML? What are you going to with the XML? The sample you posted is unnecessarily verbose, you probably won't need half of the stuff there.

Comment: well i need the xmelement becasue my service retruns a xmlelemnt object

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? In the later versions, you can use LINQ to XML, which is much simpler.

Comment: @Natasha, I don't understand. You have some service that returns `XmlElement` to you? Then why do you want to create another `XmlElement`?

Comment: @John Saunders i am using .net 4.0

Comment: Then you'd be better off using LINQ to XML and turning the final result into an XmlElement from XElement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make that into an Extension Method on the Object Type so you don't have to put that method in a bunch of different classes.